# How to add new Device class to Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am new to Linux Device Driver and learning how to add new Device class to existing class of devices .

```
  static struct class fpga = {
  .name = "fpga",
  .owner = THIS_MODULE,
  .dev_attrs = fpgaattrs,
  };
```

1. Is it the right way to add a new Device class named fpga?
2. Can anybody explain the concept of device class and how it works?

Answer (score 0):

I have always used [`class_create()`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.33/include/linux/device.h#L284).  Unfortunately, this interface appears to be newer than what is documented in [LDD3](http://tjworld.net/books/ldd3/).  I learned about it from [Essential Linux Device Drivers](http://elinuxdd.com/) which was written around the 2.6.24 kernel, but this book isn't published online.

When you want to unload your module, you need to destroy the class again with [`class_destroy()`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.33/drivers/base/class.c#L260).